# Are there differences in meaning for 「ワイルド」 and 'wild'?

Tags: translation, loanwords

The word ワイルド is generally translated as 'wild' in English. Of course there are many instances where this is the appropriate translation. But I feel like there is a wider range of meanings in Japanese which are not encompassed by 'wild' in English. I don't have specific examples, but I feel like it can mean 'daring', 'unconventional', 'masculine', 'raw', etc. I can't quite put my finger on it, but it feels like there is a difference in the range of meanings expressed by 'wild' and「ワイルド」.

(1) Do you agree that there are different nuances?
(2) How would you translate ワイルド (with examples, if possible).

Answer (score 2):

1) I agree that there are different nuances.

2) I don't know all the nuances, but I think this comedian has done a lot to influence the word's meaning (comically) in Japan's pop culture.

- (Japanese) 
  https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AE%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93
- (English)
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugi-chan

His 「ワイルド、だろう？」 catch phrase is used when he means something along the lines of "(I am or what I'm doing is) Crazy, right?" where he means to imply that he's "daring", "adventurous", "against convention" in a cool way. (His actions in his skits, however, aren't that "wild", which is a source of his comedy).

Personal observation: though this "wild" is comical, it's since become a pop culture phrase to the point that I believe his "wild" has become a dominant definition of "wild".